# How to exit a process which is asking for an input from the user in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I want to invoke a command line process, lets say that process accepts user input like "Press enter to exit".

How to invoke suck kind of process and get the return value from that process?

The above code crashes in that scenario in Powershell?

```
function InvokeProcess 
{
param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$ExeName,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$Arguments
    )
    try 
    {
        [string] $ExecutablePath = $Path + $ExeName
        $FullPath = [string] $ExecutablePath + $Arguments 
        $result = & $FullPath
    }
    catch 
    {
        $Msg = "Exception: $error[0]"
       WriteLog $Msg "Error"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting the parameter names to ask for input?  You could use a `Read-Host`.  Are you wanting the powershell window to wait for the executable to finish running? You could use `Wait-Process`.

Comment: `$result = & $ExecutablePath $Arguments`

Comment: @Bryce I am not waiting for any process. That process is prompting for an input to exit, because of which my code crashes.

Comment: I found the issue. the issue is using + symbol $ExecutablePath + $Arguments . Thanks Brynce and Mathias

Answer (score 0):

$result = & $ExecutablePath $arg1 $arg2